# LabVIEW Binary File from Database to .rtf in .Net control

Tags: binary, rtf, labview

I have one vi where I save a .rtf file to a database like so:

[image: Upload .rtf]

Later, I get the file from the database and save it as an .rtf before I open it with another vi (*rtf viewer.vi*):

[image: .rtf save]

However, Although *rtf viewer.vi* will work with files that are not uploaded to the database, it cannot read these files. Opening a file in Notepad++ gets me the following:

> Ā؀萀ĀĀ ᄠĀ
>   �{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033\deflangfe1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0
>   Calibri;}{\f1\froman\fprq2\fcharset2 Symbol;}}
>   \viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa160\sl252\slmult1\b\f0\fs22 Known Issues:\par
>   \pard\fi-360\li720\sa160\sl252\slmult1\b0\f1\'b7\tab\f0 VI Displays no
>   error when "Print." is Selected with no printer attached\par
>   \f1\'b7\tab\f0 Arduino driver does not currently initialize with
>   startup\par \pard\sa160\sl252\slmult1\b Improvement Points:\par
>   \pard\fi-360\li720\sa160\sl252\slmult1\b0\f1\'b7\tab\f0 Time numeric
>   constants are listed in numeric format time format\par \f1\'b7\tab\f0
>   Does not support test steps longer than 50 days\b\par
>   \pard\sa160\sl252\slmult1 Change Log:\par
>   \pard\fi-360\li720\sa160\sl252\slmult1\b0\f1\'b7\tab\f0 [Date] Fixed
>   Issue with Results Display - JLS\par \f1\'b7\tab\f0 [Date] Added
>   Arduino Control -JLS\par }

The file does save, however, it's not able to be read by my viewer vi

---

## Edit:

The issue is on the download side when writing to the binary file, I've been able to eliminate it by formatting the variant as a string before writing. However, that's added a `'/00'` char after every byte which I eliminate from the string after writing:

[image: Working Code]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the database VIs, but the output in your question looks like valid RTF but with some extra junk at the beginning. Perhaps you're missing some decoding step? What do you see in a binary comparison of the uploaded and retrieved files?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this level of complexity. How would I do a **binary** comparison?

Comment: @ATE-ENGE Depends on your tools. Most source code control diff tools have this ability. If you only have LabVIEW, you could try flattening the data to string and then viewing the string in hex mode. (right-click on a string indicator, Visible Items >> Display Style, then change the style ring to Hex Display). You could compare letter by letter visually that way, or write a program to walk through the strings and compare contents.

Comment: We're talking about comparing the contents of two files, so use a straightforward Read from Binary File with the output wired to a string indicator and right-click on the indicator and choose Hex Display - no flattening needed. It looks as if the difference is near the start of the file.

Comment: I did the comparison and searched LabVIEW's help. The only difference is an added header. I can eliminate it with a find and replace string, but the operation as a whole is expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Real problem here is that the LabVIEW string uploads to the Database as an array of I 32 values so each `char` is padded. As a result, we need to convert the string into a u8 array for the LabVIEW database upload vi to work correctly as such:

[image]